# Angular SEO for a directory multi-language app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, seo, prerender

I am doing an angularjs app with a nodejs-expressjs server.

I want to do an app that it's similar to a business directory.
I have doubts about if it's possible doing it SEO friendly to the all items at the directory, either by his name or his features (tags). Always having in mind that all pages are created with AngularJS.
If it is possible, how to do that dinamically.

I implemented an example that uses prerender server (this  https://github.com/prerender/prerender) and the prerender-node library at the app server.

My example's pages, created by angularjs, does work (are SEO friendly, it appears at google's search)..but the pages are "static", and the directory it's going to add always new bussines to the directory that I want to appear in googles searching.

Besize, I want my app to be multi-language, and also have doubts about how to do all of that be multi-language, and if it is possible.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting your own Prerender server, it will serve the page "on the fly" every time Google accesses it, so it will always have the latest, dynamic content from your pages. If you're using a Prerender plugin to cache your pages, you'll need to make sure you recache them... or use our Prerender.io SaaS and we'll take care of all of the recaching for you.

It sounds like you just want Google to crawl your pages more often because of how dynamic your content might be. In order to have Google crawl your pages more often, make sure to quality inbound links from other sites to increase your PageRank.

Here is lots of advice from Google about multi language sites: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en